# Unbounded Queue in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a Scenario where I need an `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source` that comes from an external source "pushing" into the stream.

The best I've come up with is something like:

```
val (queue, source) = Source.queue[T](bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).preMaterialize()


// then call queue.offer(item) to push items into the source.
```

However, I'd really like to have an unbounded queue. Is there a straightforward way to do that?

### Edit

I need to pass a an object with an interface like:

```
trait Publisher[T] {
  def push(item: T)
  def end()
}
```

through to something that pushes data into the stream based on events it gets from possibly multiple sources (such as HTTP-requests or reading from an external queue). It *might* be possible to change it to use a different interface, but doing so would require a pretty substantial refactor.

And by "unbounded", I realize of course that it will be bounded by available memory, but I want the buffer to dynamically expand as needed rather than having a fixed size. Most critically because if the `maxBufferSize` is very large I don't want to allocate a large amount of memory for the buffer even if most of the time the buffer is mostly empty, especially since there will actually be a lot of these queues in place at once.

Comment: Can you provide some details about the external source? What does that look like

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unbounded".  You're going to be bounded by memory.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the assumption that the queue would use a fixed size buffer (backed by an array), so giving a very large `maxBufferSize` would result in high memory usage since an array of that size would be created for each queue.

After looking at the [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/0e4d41ad33dbeb00b598cb75b4d29899371bdc8c/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/Buffers.scala) I realized that if the buffer is larger than a certain size (128 at time of writing) it will switch to using a linked list. So setting a high `maxBufferSize` is ok.

However, from looking at the code, I'm now wondering if it is safe to use the queue to push elements from a different thread outside of the akka stream graph...

Comment: It's not safe to concurrently use the buffer, but the buffer is effectively private to the actor which materializes the `Source` which ensures that there's no concurrent use.  The queue which is exposed effectively sends messages to that actor.